# Are slurs on a score for piano as well?

Tags: piano, notation, keyboard, articulation, slurs

With piano I dont really see/hear the point yet of having slurs because of its sound. I find it difficult to play more legato than is normal. Please can someone enlighten me. Are slurs for piano scores or are they more for other kinds of instruments

Comment: "I find it difficult to play more legato than is normal": perhaps your normal playing is more legato than it should be.

Comment: maybe but I am still learning and was under the impression that the notes should be played legato on the piano if not instructed otherwise. You are obviously saying that this is wrong?

Comment: It really depends on the period and the style, but you can infer from the existence of the legato slur that any composer who used the slur did not intend unslurred passages to be legato, or at least intended them to be left to the performer's discretion.  For music written before legato slurs were employed in keyboard music, the question is rather more difficult.

Answer (score 7):

Slurs are routinely used in piano scores. Sometimes they just represent phrasing, but they also represent legato playing. They clarify from other types of less legato articulation (e.g., staccato). Two-note slurs have particular meaning: in most classical keyboard music, they mean to play the first note legato and the second note staccato, or otherwise detached from the following note.

Comment: "Two-note slurs have particular meaning: in most classical music...": not including vocal music.  I would also question the choice of words as saying "staccato" usually results in an accent (even though it shouldn't), whereas the second note in a group of two slurred notes should almost always be unaccented.

Comment: couldnt you just leave out the slurs and put a dot on the staccato note?

Comment: @armani No, because if the first note of the pair isn't specifically marked, then it's up to the pianist how to articulate it. It would be perfectly reasonably to interpret that the first note should have a slight separation from the second, staccato one.

Comment: @armani two things: first, the second note isn't necessarily staccato.  It is similar to staccato because it is detached from the following note, but the intention is different.  In the case of a two-note slur, the point is to show that the two notes form a single gesture.  The more important element of this is the attachment between the two notes.  The detachment of the second note from the following note only serves to highlight the attachment between the slurred notes.  Second, the best realization of a two note slur will be different depending on the piece's period and style.

Comment: Often in a 2-note slur for piano the second will be played a little softer than the first to suggest continuity despite the decay of the sound.

Comment: Re-reading my previous comment, I realize that truncating the quote made my comment ambiguous.  Two-note slurs in vocal music do have a particular meaning; it's just that the particular meaning is different from the meaning in instrumental music (which generally has nothing to do with phrasing, because the slurs simply indicate text underlay).

Answer (score 2):

Slurs indicate *phrasing*, not articulation. Indeed *often* phrasing is done by playing legato and separating the phrases, but in principal it is matter of interpretation, style, specific notes in specific composition. Articulation is a tool that can be used to realize phrasing.

> couldnt you just leave out the slurs and put a dot on the staccato note

*Staccato* is a very distinct articulation of playing a note very short. It is not synonymous with not playing legato.

Comment: The comment you're responding to was specifically asking about two-note slurs, which are not phrasing slurs.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for spotting, rephrased the answer.